# Can I create a thread from gc-UNsafe procedure? (Nim)

Tags: multithreading, nim-lang

At some point in my console application I want to output an image.
While displaying the image(in a separate window) my console program should not stop,
so I would create a thread for gui and invoke some lib there to open new window and draw the image.

The problem is to start a thread the procedure(thread starts with) has to be gc-safe and it is not the case for most GUI libraries:

- NiGui relies on `var app*: App` global variable, which can't be passed to the thread as argument because `App` type is private(can't be accessed in my app)
- wNim - here `app` variable is created local but you have to run `app.mainLoop()` which is not gc-safe

and so on.

I started with Nim yesterday and may not know much, it seems like there will be no such problem with other languages.

Would diving into library source code and trying to change it be the only solution?

What would you suggest I do?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `NiGui`, where the goal is to access private symbols,
here are some solutions:

- use `import xxx{.all.}`, then you have access to all symbols in xxx, including private ones
- use `include` instead of `import` (not recommend)